# CRM anonymous type#3 Cannot be assigned to

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011, anonymous-types

We have Dynamics CRM 20111. On a custom entity we have a field called new_FlagReported, which is datatype 2-option set.  In C# I need to update this flag to true.

I collect all the records that need to be updated using Linq, and with that collection I coded:

```
foreach (var rec in CustomRecs)
{
        xrm.ClearChanges();

        rec.new_FlagReported = true;
        xrm.UpdateObject(rec);
        xrm.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, the assignment to true is giving a compile-time error of:

"Property of Index 'AnonymousType#3.new_FlagReported' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

I don't understand why this field is read-only.

What exactly is an anonymous type in this context?
What is AnonymousType#3 as opposed to any other type?
How did my field become "anonymous"?
Can I recreate it as non-anonymous?
How can I update this field?

Thank you for you help.

Update:
This is what I have now, with no compile time errors:

```
var CustomRecs= from cr in xrm.new_customRecordSet
                           where cr.new_crID.Equals(sg.Id)
                           select cr;

            foreach (var rec in CustomRecs)
            {
                xrm.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
                xrm.ClearChanges();
                rec.new_FlagReported = true;
                xrm.UpdateObject(rec);
                xrm.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: just to be sure, the field is "two options" or one optionset with two items? you are using early bound, can you navigate to the definition of new_FlagReported and post that inside your question as well?

Comment: It is two-options. In the end, I changed the LINQ Select to not specify field names (which, regrettably, I did not show in my original post). This allowed me to code rec.new_FlagReported = true. However, I do not understand why this makes a difference, since the record set collected is still var, and the foreach loop acts on a variable which is still specified as var. Isn't it the "var" which makes the object anonymous as opposed to having a real datatype?  I  have posted my final code below.

Comment: If your Linq query said select new { new_FlagReported = cr.new_FlagReported }, you're telling Linq to create a new anonymous type with a field called new_FlagReported.  It won't automatically map to your proxy class.

Comment: the var keyword does not make the type anonymous.  the result of the working linq query is IQueryable and it's strongly typed.  var just says "I don't care what the type is" (implicit type).  You have to use it when working with anonymous types because there is no class definition for the anonymous type, but it's the new {} that makes something anonymous.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Scott, thank you for taking the time to explain. I will read up on this stuff, including "proxy classes".